# traceroute command not working in android

Tags: android

I am trying to execute `traceroute` command following way:

```
Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process p = r.exec("traceroute  google.com");
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            Log.d(tag,inputLine);
}
```

But it is giving me the following error:

> > java.io.IOException: Error running exec().
> >     Commands: [traceroute, 202.164.36.66]
> >     Working Directory: null
> >     Environment: null

It works fine for `ping` or any other command of linux, please help.

Comment: @shadow Wizard, Please write some comments where the problem is

Comment: Your code was not formatted correctly and your grammar needed some improvements as well. See how I edited and feel free to do that yourself in the future.

Answer (score 2):

There is no Traceroute installed on the device, so this will not work.

Comment: @repc find this link http://www.androidzoom.com/android_applications/tools/network-tools_baken.html                                       how they have implemented traceroute in their application??

Comment: Karan, maybe they have bundled a native port of traceroute with the SDK app? That's how app writers usually do that sort of thing - see for example Titanium Backup; they bundle BusyBox and SQLite with the app to ensure you always have a known working version available.